# Mysql Filter matches based on previously selected filter values?

Tags: mysql, performance, filter

I'm seeing this type of filter everywhere, I know that Magento have same principle.

So, what is the deal. Easy and solution is to filter strict by value and exclude any filter options that dont have same value. What I'm trying to do, as [this web site](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/laptop-computers/all-laptops/pcmcat138500050001.c?id=pcmcat138500050001) and tons of do is to filter by value BUT to allow selecting multiple values within same attribute. So it's all about maches (I know how to filter products by selected filter, that is not about it, just about matches)

Most logicaly solution is EAV, but as many joins make even slower query, I cron it over time to "one-happy-table" , and table structure is :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `filter` (
  `ProductID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `AttributeID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ValueID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `ProductID_AttributeID_ValueID` (`ProductID`,`AttributeID`,`ValueID`),
  KEY `ProductID` (`ProductID`),
  KEY `ValueID` (`ValueID`),
  KEY `AttributeID` (`AttributeID`)
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
```

And Here is Query I'm using to accomplish that. Query give me results I need, but is slow.

```
        SELECT  SQL_NO_CACHE 
        F.AttributeID,     
        F.ValueID,
        (SELECT COUNT(ProductID) 
        FROM filter AS FP
        WHERE F.ValueID = FP.ValueID
              AND (ProductID IN (SELECT ProductID
                                FROM   filter
                                WHERE
                                ValueID IN ( '33' ))
              OR AttributeID = (SELECT  AttributeID
                                FROM   filter
                                WHERE   ValueID IN ( '33' ) LIMIT 1))

         )  AS Items
        FROM filter AS F
        GROUP BY F.AttributeID,F.ValueID
```

When Filter table have more than 5000 records, it is slower and slower.
Tried different indexes, table storage engines. When I add about 5000 products, and every product have, for example 7 filter-values, than Query takes about 16 seconds. Least query time I made is 5.5 seconds, but I need faster than that...

Does anyone have any idea what to do to make things faster?
I want to accomplish speed like [here](http://www.winwin.rs/laptop-i-tablet-racunari/laptop-notebook-racunari.html)! :)

Comment: **EAV** is a nightmare; avoid it.

Comment: I made it. Using temporary table.
I agree that EAV is nightmare but i dont see any other solution for filters. 
One way or another, I also ending Up with one table periodicaly populated due to no-need for real-time filter update.

Comment: [A compromise design](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav).